# Pandas дописывание в конец CSV файла

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Есть вот такой csv файл

```
,Date,Model,Mark
0,2019-02-15,Q2612X,HP
1,2019-02-15,TK-1150,Kyocera
2,2019-02-15,MP2000,Ricoh
3,2019-02-26,CE255X,HP
```

Дописываю в конец файла

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ['Date', 'Model', 'Mark']

data = [
['2019-02-28', 'Q2612X', 'HP']
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df.to_csv(r'cart.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

Строка дописывается

```
,Date,Model,Mark
0,2019-02-15,Q2612X,HP
1,2019-02-15,TK-1150,Kyocera
2,2019-02-15,MP2000,Ricoh
3,2019-02-26,CE255X,HP
0,2019-02-28,Q2612X,HP
```

Но индекс принимает нулевое значение. Подскажите как реализовать продолжение индекса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проще всего отказаться от записи индекса вообще:

```
df.to_csv(..., index=False)
```

При чтении такого CSV файла Pandas автоматически создаст индекс, начинающийся с нуля.

Comment: Благодарю, оказалось все супер просто :)

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете изменить значение индекса в вашем `df` так:

```
df.index = [4,]
```

Если вы не знаете какое значение присваивать, то нужно посчитать строки в файле. Можно так:

```
with open('test.csv') as f:
    lines_count = sum(1 for _ in f) - 1
```